# Salesforce Report returns varying #rows depending on #columns - same filter

Tags: api, reporting

When Running a report on Opportunity for all opportunities, All time and criteria Opportunity Record Type = Deal I am getting around 70 k records. The report has 48 columns.

I used force.com explorer to extract by putting the same condition and I got 100 K records.

Then I modified the report by removing all the columns except 1 column Opportunity Record Type and run the report and I got 100 k records.
I am not able to understand why with 48 columns the result is 70 k and with one column is 100 K.
Is this a bug with salesforce reporting?

Comment: are you sure you weren't logged in as another user when you were running from salesforce? Also try to export the report as CSV instead of an XLS and see if the results vary, I have had similar issues with reporting exports.

Comment: Yes I was logged in with System Admin Profile and not as some other user.

Comment: did you try the csv option when exporting instead of xls?

Comment: It might be helpful if you posted the exact query you used in your code. There may be something subtle that's missing. Is there a difference between the query that had 48 columns and returned 70k records vs the one that returned 100 queries? Its my impression there was. Syntax can bite you in these instances and I don't think any of us can give you a valid answer without first seeing the exact queries you used.

Comment: Using salesforce reporting, I ran the report using the single criteria Opportunity Record Type= Deal with all 48 columns the results return with the 70. I removed all the fields except Opportunity ID and ran the report now it came with the 100K records.